# Interpreting formulas with ΣΣ (two sigma) in Python

Tags: python, math, mathematical-expressions

Consider the function f(x,y) that equals two sigma (ΣΣ) where *i* ranges from 1 to 10 and (first sigma) and *j* ranges from 1 to 10 (second sigma) of the quantity {ix^2 + jy^3)

I believe the first sigma would be an inner loop and the second sigma an outer loop, but I am having trouble rewriting this into Python.

How can I convert this into Python?

[image: Please click to see the mathematical expression. I cannot embed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested summation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475717/nested-summation-in-python)

Comment: The expressions are a bit different but I guess it potentially could, yes. I accepted an answer supplied by AKX. The other solutions are good to know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no mathematician, but as far as I could tell, that would translate to

```
def f(x, y):
    return sum(
        sum(
            i * x ** 2 + j * y ** 3
            for j in range(1, 11)
        )
        for i in range(1, 11)
    )
```

or written out as for loops,

```
def f(x, y):
    value = 0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            value += i * x ** 2 + j * y ** 3
    return value
```

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical formula can be rewritten without summation, leading to this simple function:

```
def f(x, y):
    return 550 * (x * x  + y * y * y)
```

Here is how it is derived:

∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub>∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub>² + ³

= 10∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub>² + 10∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub>³

= 10²∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub> + 10³∑<sub><sub>=1..10</sub></sub>

Using [triangular number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

= 10²(10⋅11)/2 + 10³(10⋅11)/2

= 550(² + ³)

Comment: Thanks Trincot. Sorry I already accepted AKX answer before seeing any more solutions really but I hope they will all help others in case they have a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer's approaches all work. Often the "pythonic" approach is to define a list comprehension before using `sum` so another approach would be:

```py
def f(x, y):
    return sum([(i * x ** 2 + j * y ** 3) for i in range(1,11) for j in range(1, 11)]);
```